# Avoiding hardcoded ip addresses in Android

Tags: java, android, security, hardcoded

I use the following approach to store the server ip address in my android project so that the server url can be accessed by other classes.

```
   interface GlobalConstants{
       String SERVER_URL = "192.168.xx.xx";
   }
```

However, this approach requires recompiling each time the IP address changes and decompiling will expose the server url. Is there a better approach to initialize SERVER_URL ?

I tried System.setProperty() and System.getProperty() but still it is done at runtime. Is there a way to use something like a configuration file to store IP address and make it configurable?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: i think there is no way for you to bypass the compiling and building of apk for that.

Comment: Why in the world aren't you just using DNS?

Comment: @chrylis This was an attempt to test the code by accessing localhost of PC over wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in gradle.build

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"http:TempRequest\""
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"http:TempRequest\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Then you can acess it using `BuildConfig` class that android studio will generate.

For example

```
String url = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL + "endpoint";
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This, is what I've been looking for although it doesn't eliminate the need of recompiling.. Thanks.